# how add footer and headers on wkhtmltopdf? (Django)

Tags: django, header, wkhtmltopdf

My views look like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import View
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateView
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateResponse

class MyPDF(PDFTemplateView):
    filename = 'my_pdf.pdf'
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    header_template='header.html'
    footer_template='footer.html'
    context={'title': 'Testis'}
    cmd_options = {'margin-top': 3}


    def get(self, request):
        response = PDFTemplateResponse(request=request,
                                   template=self.template_name,
                                   context=self.context,
                                   header_template=self.header_template,
                                   footer_template=self.footer_template,
                                   cmd_options=self.cmd_options
                                   )
        return response
```

I have `footer.html` and `headers.html`, but is doesn't work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

May be you don't put the doctype in footers and headers. I had a similar problem, I think.
[How to add headers and footers with django-wkhtmltopdf in my class based views with PDFTemplateResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512009/add-headers-and-footers-pdf-with-django-wkhtmltopdf-in-my-class-based-views-with/33529724#33529724)

Answer (score -1):

footer and header should already be contained in the template, which generate PDF.