# How to add headers and footers with django-wkhtmltopdf in my class based views with PDFTemplateResponse

Tags: python, django, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, django-class-based-views

I want to generate a pdf with headers, actually I'm working on cygwin andI don't know if something in my code is wrong or not, because I based my code in this examples [Creating PDFs with django (wkhtmltopdf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232691/creating-pdfs-with-django-wkhtmltopdf). This is my code:

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateResponse

GenerateReportPdf(View):
    def __init__(self):
        self.template = 'pdf_template.html'

    def get(self, request):
        ...
        response = PDFTemplateResponse(
                                       request=request,
                                       template=self.template,
                                       filename='report.pdf',
                                       context=self.context,
                                       show_content_in_browser=True,
                                       cmd_options={'margin-top': 30,},
                                       header_template='header.html',
                                       )
```

my html code may be simple but it shows something and I render a PDF successfuly but not the header.
header.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://www.someplaceintheworld/some.png" alt="some logo" />
</body>
</html>
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', login_required(views.GenerateReportPdf.as_view()), name='index'),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1645 only need put the doctype to each html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://www.someplaceintheworld/some.png" alt="some logo" />
</body>
</html>
```